# Differentiating between hyperlinks in the code of hyperlink handler

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

How to reference specific hyperlinks which are named delete and not the others that have different names in the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Range(ActiveCell.Address).Name = "Delete"

MsgBox ("Activated - Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink - before IF-ELSE")

If Range(ActiveCell.AddressLocal).Text = "Delete" Then

    ClearThatCell 'Calling ClearThatCell sub
 Else
 MsgBox ("It's regular link - NOT DELETE ")
End If


End Sub
'This SUB is clearing the selected cell
Sub ClearThatCell()
ActiveCell.Clear
 MsgBox ("The cell is cleared!")

End Sub

Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal sh As Object)
        LastSheet = sh.Name
End Sub
```

The above code is handler of the hyperlinks, but i want this code  to be used only if "Delete" hyperlink was clicked in the parent workbook.
 Thanks to all who tries to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that it does not matter which worksheet's event initiates the [Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838573.aspx) macro.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    If LCase(Target.Name) = "delete" Then
        ClearThatCell sh, Target.Range 'Calling ClearThatCell sub
    End If

End Sub

Sub ClearThatCell(ws As Worksheet, rng As Range)
    MsgBox "The " & rng.Address(0, 0) & " cell on " & ws.Name & " was clicked."
End Sub
```

Check the docs for the [Hyperlink object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835563.aspx) and [Hyperlink members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837970.aspx) to see what you else you can do with the hyperlink.

Comment: Thank's Jeeped, it's exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    If Target.TextToDisplay = "Delete" Then

        Debug.Print "deleting"
        'do stuff

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for you respond, but unfortunately your code didn't work for me.